# How to create unique rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where rows are duplicated. I need to create unique rows from this. I tried a couple of options but they don't seem to work

```
  l1 <-summarise(group_by(l,bowler,wickets),economyRate,d=unique(date))
```

This works for some rows but also gives the error "Expecting a single value". The dataframe 'l' looks like this

```
     bowler overs maidens  runs wickets economyRate       date opposition
     (fctr) (int)   (int) (dbl)   (dbl)       (dbl)     (date)      (chr)
1  MA Starc     9       0    51       0        5.67 2010-10-20      India
2  MA Starc     9       0    27       4        3.00 2010-11-07  Sri Lanka
3  MA Starc     9       0    27       4        3.00 2010-11-07  Sri Lanka
4  MA Starc     9       0    27       4        3.00 2010-11-07  Sri Lanka
5  MA Starc     9       0    27       4        3.00 2010-11-07  Sri Lanka
6  MA Starc     6       0    33       2        5.50 2012-02-05      India
7  MA Starc     6       0    33       2        5.50 2012-02-05      India
8  MA Starc    10       0    50       2        5.00 2012-02-10  Sri Lanka
9  MA Starc    10       0    50       2        5.00 2012-02-10  Sri Lanka
10 MA Starc     8       0    49       0        6.12 2012-02-12      India
```

The date is unique and can be used to get the rows for which the row can be selected. Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: It is because `summarise` returns a single value for each combination of the groups.  If there are multiple unique dates in a combination, it results in imbalance.  It is better to post the dput of example data and expected output.

Comment: The dplyr authors are considering making an extension to support this (what akrun was talking about), looks like: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154

Comment: Please, can you provide the code to create the sample data.frame with your question? This will allow to easily test the correctness of answers without burdening the poster to recreate your data. - Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example dataset, there are more than one `unique` elements of 'date' per each 'bowler', 'wickets' combination.  One option would be to `paste` the `unique` 'date' together

```
l %>%
    group_by(bowler, wickets) %>% 
    summarise(economyRate= mean(economyRate), d = toString(unique(date)))
```

Or create 'd' as a `list` column

```
l %>%
    group_by(bowler, wickets) %>% 
    summarise(economyRate= mean(economyRate), d = list(unique(date)))
```

With respect to 'economyRate', I am guessing the OP need the `mean` of that.

If we need to create a column of `unique` date in the original dataset, use `mutate`

```
l %>% 
    group_by(bowler, wickets) %>%
    mutate(d = list(unique(date)))
```

As the OP didn't provide the expected output, the below could be also the result

```
l %>%
     group_by(bowler, wickets) %>% 
     distinct(date)
```

Or as @Frank mentioned

```
l %>%
  group_by(bowler,wickets,date) %>%
  slice(1L)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! That was what I wanted. I finally did with the following code                                                                                                             l1 <- l %>% group_by(bowler,wickets,economyRate) %>%  distinct(date)

Answer (score 1):

If I get the intention of th OP right, he is asking to simply remove the duplicate rows. So, I would use

```
unique(l1)
```

That's what `?unique` says:

> unique returns a vector, data frame or array like x but with duplicate elements/rows removed.

Comment: Use `dplyr::distinct` to keep only similar rows. But it will not work here.

Comment: @PaulRougieux What is the benefit of using `dplyr` over base function `unique`?

Comment: See ?distinct, you can specify "Variables to use when determining uniqueness." For example `a <- data.frame(i=c(1,1,3),j=c(1,1,1))`, `distinct(a)` is the same as `unique(a)`, but you can also do `distinct(a,j)`, `distinct(a,i)`. Plus distinct is similar to SQL database terminology.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `dplyr::distinct`. Looks like the `dplyr`equivalent of `data.table::unique(a, by = "i")`.

Answer (score 1):

## Data

```
l <- read.table(text = "bowler overs maidens runs wickets economyRate date opposition
1 MA_Starc 9 0 51 0 5.67 2010-10-20 India
2 MA_Starc 9 0 27 4 3.00 2010-11-07 Sri-Lanka
3 MA_Starc 9 0 27 4 3.00 2010-11-07 Sri-Lanka
4 MA_Starc 9 0 27 4 3.00 2010-11-07 Sri-Lanka
5 MA_Starc 9 0 27 4 3.00 2010-11-07 Sri-Lanka
6 MA_Starc 6 0 33 2 5.50 2012-02-05 India
7 MA_Starc 6 0 33 2 5.50 2012-02-05 India
8 MA_Starc 10 0 50 2 5.00 2012-02-10 Sri-Lanka
9 MA_Starc 10 0 50 2 5.00 2012-02-10 Sri-Lanka
10 MA_Starc 8 0 49 0 6.12 2012-02-12 India")
```

## Distinct

Use dplyr::distinct to remove duplicated rows.

```
ldistinct <- distinct(l)
#     bowler overs maidens runs wickets economyRate       date
# 1 MA_Starc     9       0   51       0        5.67 2010-10-20
# 2 MA_Starc     9       0   27       4        3.00 2010-11-07
# 3 MA_Starc     6       0   33       2        5.50 2012-02-05
# 4 MA_Starc    10       0   50       2        5.00 2012-02-10
# 5 MA_Starc     8       0   49       0        6.12 2012-02-12
#   opposition
# 1      India
# 2  Sri-Lanka
# 3      India
# 4  Sri-Lanka
# 5      India
l2 <- summarise(group_by(ldistinct,bowler,wickets),
                economyRate,d=unique(date))
# Error: expecting a single value
```

But it's not enough here, there are still many dates for 
one combination of bowler and wickets.

## Collapse values together

By pasting multiple values together you will see that there are many dates and many economyRate for a single combination of bowler and wickets.

```
l3 <- summarise(group_by(l,bowler,wickets),
                economyRate = paste(unique(economyRate),collapse=", "),
                d=paste(unique(date),collapse=", "))
l3

#     bowler wickets economyRate                      d
#     (fctr)   (int)       (chr)                  (chr)
# 1 MA_Starc       0  5.67, 6.12 2010-10-20, 2012-02-12
# 2 MA_Starc       2      5.5, 5 2012-02-05, 2012-02-10
# 3 MA_Starc       4           3             2010-11-07
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I took an unusual route to doing this disection, but I let the date remain a factor when it came over from the csv file I created. you could easily the date column to a factor with

```
l1$date<-as.factor(l1$date)
```

This will make that row a non-date row, you could also convert to character, either will work fine. This is what it looks like structurally.

```
 str(l1)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ bowler     : Factor w/ 2 levels "(fctr)","MA": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ overs      : Factor w/ 2 levels "(int)","Starc": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ maidens    : Factor w/ 5 levels "(int)","10","6",..: 5 5 5 5 5 3 3 2 2 4
 $ runs       : Factor w/ 2 levels "(dbl)","0": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ wickets    : Factor w/ 6 levels "(dbl)","27","33",..: 6 2 2 2 2 3 3 5 5 4
 $ economyRate: Factor w/ 4 levels "(dbl)","0","2",..: 2 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 2
 $ date       : Factor w/ 6 levels "(date)","3","5",..: 5 2 2 2 2 4 4 3 3 6
 $ opposition : Factor w/ 6 levels "(chr)","10/20/2010",..: 2 3 3 3 3 6 6 4 4 5
 $ X.1        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","India","Sri": 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2
 $ X.2        : Factor w/ 2 levels "","Lanka": 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

After that it is about making sure that you are using the sub-setting grammar properly with the most concise query:

```
l2<-l1[!duplicated(l1$date),]
```

And this is what is returned, 5 rows of unique data:

```
   bowler overs maidens runs wickets economyRate date opposition   X.1   X.2
2      MA Starc       9    0      51           0 5.67 10/20/2010 India      
3      MA Starc       9    0      27           4    3  11/7/2010   Sri Lanka
7      MA Starc       6    0      33           2  5.5   2/5/2012 India      
9      MA Starc      10    0      50           2    5  2/10/2012   Sri Lanka
11     MA Starc       8    0      49           0 6.12  2/12/2012 India
```

The only thing you need to be careful of is to keep that comma after the `!duplicated(l1$date)` to be sure that ALL columns are searched and included in the final subset.

If you want dates or characters you can `as.POSIXct` or `as.character` convert them to a usable format for the rest of your manipulation.

I hope this is useful to you!